# Getting JSON to work with Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am pulling in my marker data via JSON.
When i was developing my local copy i had this in a JS file and just called it using

```
<script src="assets/js/locations.js"></script>
```

I am now moving the site onto a CMS (ExpressionEngine) and because the marker data is dynamic I have a JS template which now holds the JSON data.

I now have to include the file as **(notice that there is no file extension)**

```
<script src="http://domain.com/map/locations"></script>
```

Here is an example of the JSON I have.

```
var locations = [

    [2, 51.39006, -0.02976, 'telecommunications', 'Test 2', '<div><img src="http://localhost/map/assets/graphics/info_window/default.jpg" alt="Test 2" width="105" height="70" style="float:right;"> <p>fdgj fdh uhfj bfd nibjdfjb ndfjn fd vfn vbjdc&nbsp; ifs n ei klmvf.cx fi fskn d</p></div>', '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Read more</a>' ],   
    [1, 51.51400, -0.12002, 'transport', 'Test map marker', '<div><img src="{image:url:thumb}" alt="Test map marker" width="{image:width:thumb}" height="{image:height:thumb}" style="float:right;"> <p>eubnglrsk nekfldb jndklvcbv jdnfhl kvbmd klbndvl kbjn dkbnm lkd nbmfljeb ygdjfjn</p></div>', '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Read more</a>' ]  

];
```

This is the marker loop for the map

```
var markers = [];

    // Looping through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][4],
            icon: iconSrc[locations[i][3]]
        });
        markers.push(marker);


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent("<div class='cont_box' id='" + locations[i][0] + "'>" + "<h2>" +locations[i][4] + "</h2>" + "<div class='cont'>" + locations[i][5] + "</div><div style='clear:both;'></div><div class='link'>" + locations[i][6] + "</div></div>");
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    }// END for loop
```

Obviously the error I get when I reference the JSON data rendered by the CMS is ::

**ReferenceError: locations is not defined**

The URL is valid, just it doesn't seem to be pulled in like when i use a JS file.

I don't know if it would be better for me to call the file within the maps JS code itself.

Any suggestions on how I could make this work would be great

Comment: please post a link, It appears that the issue here is much more related to your CMS than to google-maps, impossible to answer without knowing what your CMS creates.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I think it maybe that I am not calling an actual file extenstion. I don't think it is anything to do with the CMS or Google maps, that why I wanted to look at other ways of pulling in the JSON

Comment: @Dr.Molle I will get an example for you tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 ideas.

1. in your script tag declare the type (do you know if your overall page is html5?):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/map/locations"></script>
> ```

My other idea is to load your data in the code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain.com/map/locations', true);
xhr.onload = function() {load you markers here}
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, in your HTML script, you are sourcing the "locations.js" script before you source the script that creates the map.  Using firebug or the chrome console, ensure that both scripts are properly being loaded by your browser.

It would be helpful to see a html snippet where you load these scripts.

Also, did you mean to write:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/map/locations.js"></script>
```

above instead of:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/map/locations"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am loading the locations JSON before the map JS. The before and after script tags are correct, the CMS does not produce a extension for templates, so the URL produced for the JS file is http://domain.com/map/locations (without .js at the end)